# Problems in Safari using .css jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I've a problem when I try to change some color text with jQuery (only happend in Safari).

My code is:

```
$("#myDiv").css("color","#004a93");
$("#myDiv2").css("color","#004a93");
$("#myDiv3").css("color","#004a93");
```

This works in others like Chrome, Firefox, IE...but not in Safari. It's strange because his console not give me any error in JavaScript.

Why can be the error?

Edit:

This is all my function code

```
function changeBack(){
    if ((id=="") || (isNaN(id))){
        id='01';
    }   

    var nombre = "tarjeton-mediano-";
    var ruta = "/imagenes/tarjetones/tarjeton-mediano-"+id+".png";
    var codTarjeta = "";
    var colorTexto = "";

    $("#muestra-tarjeton-escogido").css("background-image","url('"+ruta+"')");

    switch(id){
        case '01':
        case '02':
            if (id=='01'){
                codTarjeta="clasico";
                colorTexto="rgb(126,106,63)";
            }else{
                codTarjeta="floral";
                colorTexto="rgb(0,74,147)";
            }
            $("#textomensaje").css({width:'500px',height:'120px',marginLeft:'25px',marginTop:'110px'});
            $("#destinatariomsj").css("color","#004a93");
            $("#textomsj").css("color","#004a93");
            $("#nombremsj").css("color","#004a93");
            break;
        case '03':
            $("#textomensaje").css({width:'320px',height:'140px',marginLeft:'25px',marginTop:'90px'});
            break;
        case '04':
        case '05':
            $("#textomensaje").css({width:'500px',height:'120px',marginLeft:'25px',marginTop:'160px'});
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/6L0vxu5h/2/

Comment: Is your code in `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: your code is good and should work in all browsers.. so try to merge that in one line if that will make sense .. try $(document).ready(function(){$('#myDiv,#myDiv2,#myDiv3').css('color','#004a93');}); but surly its nothing wrong in javascript

Comment: I've this code inside a function and works in all browsers...but this part, in Safari (Windows version) isn't works... I put all code to my function (sorry, I forget put all the code).

Comment: Just an fyi, the version of Safari in Windows hasn't been updated since version 5.1.7... the latest in OSX is 8. I found that the two versions act very different.

Comment: Yes, I know but who design the website use Mac and I'm not sure if it's works.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I used this code like include in php but now, I'm using like separate page and it's works.

I'm not change my code jet...maybe the problem it's like sais @Ricky in a comment: the Safari version on Windows is very very older and have mane bugs.

Thanks for all comments and help!